# When I delete pre-installed apps (iMovie, GarageBand, etc.): What are the consequences?

Tags: macos, applications, mac-appstore

Some of the apps, which come with MacOS, are really big and I don't use them.

**Can I simply delete them with "Command" + "Del" like normal files?**

Just in case one would need them later: **Can they become re-installed via AppStore or do I have to set the whole system back the factory settings?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I simply delete them with "Command" + "Del" like normal files?
>
> […]
>
> Can they become re-installed via AppStore […] ?

## Yes, but...

Only ***some*** built-in apps can be deleted and re-installed.

You can delete them from Finder (as well as by other means) using different methods (including the one you have described - which actually moves the app file to the trash).

To delete apps (including *some* built-in apps), take a look at [Uninstall apps on your Mac - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202235):

- [Use Launchpad to delete apps that were downloaded from the App Store](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202235#:%7E:text=use%20launchpad%20to%20delete%20apps%20that%20were%20downloaded%20from%20the%20app%20store)
- [Use the Finder to delete apps](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202235#:%7E:text=the%20Finder%20instead.-,use%20the%20finder%20to%20delete%20apps)

[image: screenshot taken on macOS Ventura of Launchpad when trying to delete Keynote]

**Note** : As mentioned above, some built-in apps ***cannot*** be deleted (such as Photos, Mail, Notes, Messages, TextEdit, Music, etc.) because they are an intrinsic part of the OS.

### Download originally built-in apps from the App Store

Only some of the originally built-in apps can be found in the App Store. These apps are and can be downloaded at:

- [**GarageBand** - direct download link from the App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/garageband/id682658836)
- [**iMovie** - direct download link from the App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/imovie/id408981434)
- [**Keynote** - direct download link from the App Store](https://apps.apple.com/fr/app/keynote/id409183694)
- [**Numbers** - direct download link from the App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/numbers/id409203825)
- [**Pages** - direct download link from the App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pages/id409201541)

### Additional info - Use [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (freeware)

*Thanks to @Tetsujin for this suggestion.*

Built-in apps may have lots of files ("extras") that can take a lot of space on your Mac and that are not deleted when deleting the app alone. This is the case of GarageBand for example:

[image: screenshot taken on macOS Mojave showing GarageBand "extra" files volume]

By default, built-in apps are protected by the system and therefore are not deletable. To make them deletable, you need to open AppCleaner's preferences and, under General, untick the "Protect default OS X / macOS apps" option:

[image: screenshot taken on macOS Mojave of AppCleaner's Preferences under the General tab]